# SignalR, websockets and go

Tags: go, websocket, signalr

I need to connect to a SignalR server from Go. I've been trying to use some libraries and articles to help me with it:

- https://github.com/x2v3/signalr
- https://github.com/devigned/signalr-go
- https://www.derpturkey.com/signalr-is-an-abomination-how-to-connect-using-raw-websockets/
- https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/

The problem is that I need to retrieve a token from a different port. My SignalR server address is `https://server:10446/endpoint`, but I need to retrieve my token from `https://server:10443/connect/token` and this is drifting from the normal SignalR protocol.

I'm able to get my token. And able to get the negotiate step getting the following response:

```json
{
    "connectionId": "JkOfCC0JykJ8hfzm8jd53w",
    "availableTransports": [
      {
        "transport": "WebSockets",
        "transferFormats": [
          "Text",
          "Binary"
        ]
      },
      {
        "transport": "ServerSentEvents",
        "transferFormats": [
          "Text"
        ]
      },
      {
        "transport": "LongPolling",
        "transferFormats": [
          "Text",
          "Binary"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I then try to get a connection by doing a websocket connection using gorilla websockets:

```sh
wss://server:10446/endpoint?transport=WebSockets&id=${ConnectionIDFromNegotiate}&connectionData=[{\"name\":\"HubName\"}]&access_token=${MyRetrievedToken}
```

At this point, I get a response that says `101`, upgraded to websocket. however, from this moment on, I'm unable to proceed with the handshake. I'm sending a message to the server, but I'm getting no response whatsoever, apart form a handshake abort after 15-20 seconds.

This is the code that I'm using to connect and send the handshake message:

```golang
    ws, resp, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err = ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(`{"protocol": "json","version": 1}`)); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

Any idea will be warmly welcomed :)

Comment: It looks like you're missing part of the message payload. Spec https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/SignalR/docs/specs/HubProtocol.md#overview
"Both the HandshakeRequest and HandshakeResponse messages must be terminated by the ASCII character 0x1E (record separator)."

Comment: You sir @Brennan, you just nailed it!
That was it. I'm getting other kinds of errors now at least!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was given by [Brennan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9175226/brennan).
Thanks a lot for it!

> It looks like you're missing part of the message payload. Spec github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/SignalR/docs/specs/… "Both the HandshakeRequest and HandshakeResponse messages must be terminated by the ASCII character 0x1E (record separator)."

Comment: Hi @Flashito, Did you get your client working? Could you share your client's code?